# Display the correct Label in jquery AutoComplete with LINQ

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm testing out the auto complete feature with jQuery, however I'm having trouble displaying the correct label. When the search involves only 1 field or criteria, it is simple:

```
var model = db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.Department.Contains(term))
                .Take(10).Select(r => new
                {
                    label = r.Department
                }).Distinct();

            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

However, if I want to deal with multiple search criteria (i.e. when the user enter a searchTerm, it will look everywhere in the table to find the matching result), for example:

```
var model = db.UserProfiles.Where(u => (u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName).Contains(term) || u.Department.Contains(term) ||
                u.JobTitle.Contains(term) || u.PhoneNumber.Contains(term) || u.Extension.Contains(term) || u.Location.Contains(term))
                .Take(10).Select(r => new
                {
                    label = //How do I display the correct label here?
                }).Distinct();

            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Expected output:

If there is a person first name "Terry", and there is also a department called "Technology" in the table, when the user type in "te", it should display both "Technology" and "Terry"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simulate a case statement in linq to entities using ternary operators, like so:

```
var model = db.UserProfiles.Select(r => new
            {
                label = (u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName).Contains(term)  ? (u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName) :
                                            u.Department.Contains(term)  ? u.Department :
                                            u.JobTitle.Contains(term)    ? u.JobTitle :
                                            u.PhoneNumber.Contains(term) ? u.PhoneNumber :
                                            u.Extension.Contains(term)   ? u.Extension :
                                            u.Location.Contains(term)    ? u.Location : null
            }).Where(l => l != null).Distinct().Take(10);

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using a blank list of string and concating each matching set one by one.

If you wanted to make this more dynamic you could use an interative process which used `.Concat`, a meta attribute on the UserProfile class, and reflection.

```
var model = (new List<string>())
    .Concat(db.UserProfiles
            .Where(u => (u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName).Contains(term))
            .Select(u => (u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName))
            .Distinct())
    .Concat(db.UserProfiles
            .Where(u => u.Department.Contains(term))
            .Select(u => u.Department)
            .Distinct())
    .Concat(db.UserProfiles
            .Where(u => u.JobTitle.Contains(term))
            .Select(u => u.JobTitle)
            .Distinct())
    .Concat(db.UserProfiles
            .Where(u => u.PhoneNumber.Contains(term))
            .Select(u => u.PhoneNumber)
            .Distinct())
    .Concat(db.UserProfiles
            .Where(u => u.Extension.Contains(term))
            .Select(u => u.Extension)
            .Distinct())
    .Concat(db.UserProfiles
            .Where(u => u.Location.Contains(term))
            .Select(u => u.Location)
            .Distinct())
    .OrderBy( s => s )//must have an orderby in order to use Take
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();

return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```